# UseInMemoryDatabase Decimals not rounded to correct length

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

In .net core I am seeding data to a database and have this as a modelbuilder inside of my DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<HistoricalInvestmentDataEntry>().Property(x => x.ClosingPrice).HasColumnType($"decimal(18,9)");
```

Now I am running unit tests and need to use the InMemoryDatabase, but the values in this Database are not rounded as I would like shown above. When I run the program normally these values are all rounded.

In the test I have this code:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase("MyTestDatabase")
    .Options;
        
_context = new SparrechnerDbContext(options);
var model = _context.Model;
_context.Seed();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The rules for processing `decimal` in SQL Server are rather complicated. In C#, the `decimal` type has a fixed precision, and that's more than the `18` specified here. I wouldn't expect the in-memory database to match SQL Server semantics exactly -- after all, this does vary per database. If your tests are actually dependent on how the database rounds, then arguably you're testing the wrong thing. If you're not, but you're absolutely dependent on how SQL Server rounds, it's probably better to use a LocalDB instance instead of an in-memory DB. Either that or involve `SqlDecimal` somehow.

Comment: Explicitly rounding values yourself before storing them (with `Decimal.Round`) is another option, even if you're normally relying on the database to do this implicitly. (All of this is assuming you *are* using `decimal` for `ClosingPrice` and not, say, `double`, otherwise you've got bigger issues.)